# I have to change the package name

Tags: package

good. I have purchased a project and I have a question since I'm new to this world of applications. The question is whether I have to change the project name in all the package references so that Google Play Console doesn't realize it's the same application, as several users have purchased the project.

I'm following the application documentation, but it doesn't say anything about changing that information.

Answer (score 0):

You can only change the app name in Play Console, but you won't be able to change the app package name.

> Package names for app files are unique and permanent, so please name them carefully. Package names can't be deleted or re-used in the future.

[Per reference](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859152?hl=en&sjid=12981543130554294143-AP)